# Jest test for helper file and external function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I need to add jest test into the current project.
however, I found that helper files here I don't know how to write the test for it

the file stores some functions like this

```
import SDK from 'privateSDK'

export function login(){
  SDK.login() // Call the native app login if webview
}
```

If you run the functions on the browser on PC, you will not get any data or effects
How Can I test the file?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you are looking for mocks, see documentation: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions#mocking-modules

Answer (score 1):

You need to mock `privateSDK` module and `login` method, then you can run your unit tests in an isolated environment which means your unit tests will not depend on the real native app `login` method.

You can check the docs here: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions#mocking-modules